# How to refresh a file in vi without it moving to the viewing window to the top of the file?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I am sometimes frustrated by vi's ability to refresh files.  Say I have a file open, call it `afile.txt`.  Then I do `:vsplit` to split the file vertically.

I scroll down to the bottom of the file in the left pane.  Then, I scroll down to the bottom of the file in the right pane.

My cursor is still in the right pane.  Next, I want to refresh the file.  So I do `:e` like a normal person would.  The problem with that is, it always moves my view of the file in the left pane back to the top.

How do I refresh the file in `vi` without it moving the opposite pane back to the top?

Thanks.

Comment: This is Vim, not Vi.

Comment: What do you mean by "refresh the file"? Reread from disk, or redisplay? The latter is Ctrl-L, the former should be done automatically by Vim if `set autoread`.

Comment: It would have to *reread from disk* in order to pick up the new changes if the file is open elsewhere, right?  so I would assume reread from disk.  I'm not sure how redisplay would ever be useful.  Thanks.